# Conditionally excluding cmdlet arguments that are null or empty

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I've written a script that calls the New-Service cmdlet to create a Windows service:

```
New-Service -Name $Name -BinaryPathName $ExecutablePath `
    -Credential $Credential -DisplayName $DisplayName `
    -Description $Description -StartupType $StartupType
```

I have a problem with the Description.  If $Description is an empty string or $null I get an error:

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Description'. 
The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, 
and then try the command again.
```

If I leave out the -Description parameter entirely the command runs without error:

```
New-Service -Name $Name -BinaryPathName $ExecutablePath `
    -Credential $Credential -DisplayName $DisplayName `
    -StartupType $StartupType
```

I can work around this problem via:

```
if ($Description)
{
    New-Service -Name $Name -BinaryPathName $ExecutablePath `
        -Credential $Credential -DisplayName $DisplayName `
        -Description $Description -StartupType $StartupType
}
else
{
    New-Service -Name $Name -BinaryPathName $ExecutablePath `
        -Credential $Credential -DisplayName $DisplayName `
        -StartupType $StartupType   
}
```

However, this seems verbose and clunky.  Is there any way of telling a Powershell cmdlet to ignore an argument that is null or empty when calling the cmdlet?

Something along the lines of:

```
New-Service -Name $Name -BinaryPathName $ExecutablePath `
    -Credential $Credential -DisplayName $DisplayName `
    -Description [IgnoreIfNullOrEmpty]$Description -StartupType $StartupType
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Parameter splatting**, documented in the conceptual [about_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) help topic,<sup>[1]</sup> is the best approach in such cases:

```
# Create a hashtable with all parameters known to have values.
# Note that the keys are the parameter names without the "-" prefix.
$htParams = @{
  Name = $Name
  BinaryPathName = $ExecutablePath
  Credential = $Credential
  DisplayName = $DisplayName
  StartupType = $StartupType
}

# Only add a -Description argument if it is nonempty.
if ($Description) { $htParams.Description = $Description }

# Use the splatting operator, @, to pass the parameters hashtable.
New-Service @htParams
```

---

<sup>[1] [chribonn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3660104/chribonn) also recommends [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts/) for an introduction to splatting.</sup>